# .net linq entity framework groupby

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a db table with columns like
DaysInTrade, PercentGain

i want a sum of PercentGain grouped by DaysInTrade

so:

```
DaysInTrade,PercentGain
1, 5
1,6
2,4
```

Would give me:

```
DaysInTrade, Sum
1, 11
2,4
```

I was not able to get intellisense working in the "select new" part unless I used something like Sum or Select.  the DIT column below shows up blank no matter if I do ts.DaysInTrade, or gts.DaysInTrade

```
        var partialQuery = (from ts in context.TradeSnapshots
                            group ts by ts.DaysInTrade
                            into gts
                            select
                            new
                                {
                                    profit = gts.Sum(s => s.PercentGain),
                                    DIT = gts.Select(ts=>ts.DaysInTrade)
                                });
        dataGridViewTradeSnapshots.DataSource = partialQuery.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the key on the grouping.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) on `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`

```
var partialQuery = (from ts in context.TradeSnapshots
                        group ts by ts.DaysInTrade
                        into gts
                        select
                        new
                            {
                                profit = gts.Sum(s => s.PercentGain),
                                DIT = gts.Key
                            });
dataGridViewTradeSnapshots.DataSource = partialQuery.ToList();
```